# MySites - moving documents from 'Personal Documents' to 'Shared Documents'

Tags: document-library, my-site

We are running SharePoint 2010 SP1 and looking at MySites.

Maybe I am missing something so hope you can help. Is there an easy way for a user to move a document from their 'Personal Documents' library to their 'Shared Documents' library? For example when they have a document that they want to share. I know there is the 'Send To' menu item but that this requires that the user enter a URL, it's not very friendly and the version history is not copied over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 2007 it's as easy as doing this:

Go to Personal Documents and select Actions, Open with Windows Explorer.  Then go to Shared Documents and do the same.  Cut the files from the Personal Documents explorere window and paste them into the Shared Documents explorer window.

I don't have a 2010 environment with My Sites to be able to give you the exact steps to do it.  Look for a similar icon on the Library tab of the ribbon, open in windows explorer.

Edit:
If you're running the Standard or Enterprise SKU, users can go into the site collection features (as they are site collection owners of their personal site) and enable to Office publishing infrastructure feature.  Then in Site Settings, there will be a content and structure link they can use to move items around.

Comment: Thanks Eric, i tried it and it works (there is still a 'Open with Explorer' action on the library ribbon). I guess i was hoping that users could stay within the browser but this is certainly an option.

Comment: Adding an additional note based on SKU.

Comment: Yeah just found that too, i'm on standard edition and it is there too, as long as publishing is turned on.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to the Shared Documents library, and copy the address from the IE Address Box
2. Go to Personal Documents
3. Choose option "Send To" > "Other Location"
4. Paste in the address copied in step 1
5. Click OK

Repeat from step 3 for each document to be copied, as you can only copy one file at a time